# Error on post action

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to post some data to my API.

Here is my repo:

```
public async Task Create(CustomerMaster entity)
{
  await trainContext.CustomerMaster.AddAsync(entity);
  await trainContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And here my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]CustomerMaster entity)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    await customerMasterRepository.Create(entity);
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = entity.Id }, entity);
}
```

I always get back a 500 when I am trying to send something with postman.

**I debug it and in my repo is adding the entity but it's never posted in the database actually.**

Am I missing something? Or what I did wrong?

Edit 1:

```
private readonly TrainContext trainContext;
public CustomerMasterRepository(TrainContext context)
{
   trainContext = context;
}
```

Edit 2: Using EF, no repo

So I have in my controller:

```
private TrainContext context;
public CustomerMasterController()
{
    context = new TrainContext();
}
```

And in my POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(CustomerMaster entity)
{
   if (entity == null)
   {
      return BadRequest();
   }
   await context.CustomerMaster.AddAsync(entity);
  // await context.SaveChangesAsync();
   return CreatedAtRoute("GetCustomer",new { id = entity.Code }, entity);
}
```

And I still get back a 500.I really don`t understand why?
I debug it and is not taking what I am posting in the entity.

Edit 3:

I create this controller using API Controller with actions generated by EF and in that case I get a 500 when I try a GET action.

Now I a really confused about from where is that 500: database connection? controller?

Comment: Without seeing your full repo, particularly how its getting an instance of your context, it's impossible to say what the issue might be. However, honestly, you should throw this repo away and just use EF directly. The repository pattern is for low-level data access. EF *already* implements the repository pattern (and does it far better than you). Additionally, calling `SaveChangesAsync` in your repo method is *highly* inefficient at best, and at worst can lead to data corruption as you're basically killing EF's ability to do work in transactions.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I edit this post, and add the context in my repo. And a lot of thanks for your advises...They teach me in school that repo is super good so that`s why I decide to use it but for sure I will google more this subject.

Comment: @AlexandraDamaschin repo's are good to create seperation of concerns in your code base and to create a manageable data flow. It's not a good idea to do persistence in a controller, like it's not a good idea to domain logic in a repository. What they teach you at school is not incorrect, but it's important to realize why patterns are useful in the first place instead of blindly applying them.

Comment: @Glubus, you are totally right. I will try to clarify all this in my head.

Comment: Did you manage to fix your problem?

Comment: I am trying to implement now with EF directly

Comment: I tried to work directly with my context but I still get back a 500.

Comment: Based on your updated code (using EF directly), there's nothing in the action itself that will throw an exception, unless there's a problem with the database (bad connection string, hasn't been migrated, etc.). Assuming the database is good, look for problems in Startup or in any custom action filters, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the controller constructor code. EF Core context should *always* be injected. Don't new it up yourself.

Comment: Debug the application and enable that it breaks at all exceptions so that you can see and tell us what Exception happens

Comment: Considering that the Get method is working and is using the same database, I will say that the connection string is good. I am using a database which I scaffold, it might be there a problem? @ChrisPratt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating this controller using EF, easier and for sure EF create all the actions better than me.